# Implementing APPLE PAY using stripe

Tags: ios, iphone, angular, ionic-framework, document

I am new to Payment Integration. I need the proper **documentation** for **Implementing Apple Pay using Stripe**. I am using ionic 3 and angular 6. Please anyone suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the original doc of the js guide for the apply pay using stripe

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button

You can try it if facing any problems post the question is SO

Comment: Thank you @Hitech. Let me try.

Comment: Hi Hitech, I have a doubt. Apple pay is not available in India and also in our Iphone, Wallet and Apple pay setting not available. So I can't able to add card details. Is it possible to implement and test?